# OpenGl ES on Iphone - Displaying and rotating 3D objects

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios4, xcode4

I'am new to Iphone, to Xcode and to openGL ES.

I looking for an example of a source code witch demonstrates how to create 3d object, rotate it with gestures and zoom in, zoom out ...

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple example how to display and rotate 3d models created with Blender: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html

The complete source can be found here: http://innerloop.biz/code/ExportTest.zip

Comment: innerloop links broken here and in blog :(    possible similar script found at:  https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export/objc_blend_2.57%20%28RC1%29

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the OpenGL SuperBible 5th Ed. It starts out with the very foundations with lots of example code (I believe the specific scenario you describe is chapter 5), and moves on to topics like platform specific development, OpenGL ES for the iPhone... - and it's a decent read, a rare quality among textbooks, in my opinion. All examples and code in the book should compile in Xcode, and they show various exceptions for individual platforms as necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the recomendation, i've looked at the book, seems to be promising ... by the way, i've found WWDC 2010 Sample Code on apple developer site. it holds lot of source code examples for different issues such as gestures and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking at this challenge as well.

I will put up my findings so far, and whack a bounty on this question to try and get some focus for it.

http://nineveh.gl/  promises to do the job, but it is in beta and even the most basic examples don't run out-of-the-box (they give compiler errors).  so I couldn't recommend it.

It is possible to integrate Unity with native iOS code, eg

http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59

http://technology.blurst.com/a-cocoa-based-frontend-for-unity-iphone-applications/

but that stuff looks scary

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules  is open source; it may be possible to lift something from there.

Answer (score 0):

I see you had answered this but a good tutorial are the Lamarche Tutorials, there is also OpenGLES 2.0 tutorials:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

Also for loading up models look up setting up the POWER VR SDK as there is all the things you need to loading up a 3d model with bone animation , textures lighting e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you have searched and looking for but you can take a look at : [http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_filters,*lighting*&_keyboard_control/15002/](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_filters,_lighting_&_keyboard_control/15002/)

in the lower portion of the page, you can see that there is the example code for macos/cocoa ..

i'm still not sure but hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had a play around with OpenGL ES a year or so ago, and I found this on-line O'Reilly book very helpful: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/

The chapters are typical of most books on this subject; math primer to 'Advanced' (typically your usual scene using shaders that implement cube-maps, bump-maps etc)

You are also able to download the source code for the examples.

Edit: I also own this book http://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-ES-2-0-Programming-Guide/dp/0321502795/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336064164&sr=8-1
Which I found was a good read with respect to OpenGL ES as-well as 3D graphics in general.