# Displaying and Rotating 3-D mesh by mouse / touch?

Tags: rotation, quaternions

Imagine a camera aimed at a sphere that is free to rotate around it's centre.

Imagine that the user can rotate this sphere by reaching out from the camera to touch the closest point on this sphere and flick it round.

This is what I'm trying to implement in iOS.

[OpenGl ES on Iphone - Displaying and rotating 3D objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140414/opengl-es-on-iphone-displaying-and-rotating-3d-objects) <-- in this linked question I'm trying to figure out a suitable framework.

I've since opted for http://nineveh.gl/ (it is still in beta, but works fine with a little nudging) and got its rotation demo working.

Everytime the user's finger moves on the touchscreen, the code catches that instantaneous vector, which will get thrown in to the overall velocity vector every update (@ 60 Hz):

```
- (void) drawView
{
    static CGPoint v = { 0.0, 0.0 };

    v.x += _vel.x;
    v.y += _vel.y;

    // resetting to 0 makes sure each touch movement only gets fed in once
    _vel.x = _vel.y = 0.0;

    float decay = 0.93;
    v.x *= decay;
    v.y *= decay;

    //  this is wrong...
    [_mesh rotateRelativeToX: v.y
                         toY: v.x
                         toZ: 0.0 ];


    [_camera drawCamera];
}
```

this resultant force should then be applied to the mesh.

what I have above initially seems to work.   if I swipe horizontally it works perfectly.   similarly vertically.   but it is only when I start to combine the rotations that it goes out of sync.   say I rotate 10° horizontally and then 10° vertically.   now it is not responding properly.

can anyone elucidate the problem?

from reading up, I suspect a solution will involve quaternions...

can anyone suggest how I can solve this? This is teh API reference I have to play with:  http://nineveh.gl/docs/Classes/NGLObject3D.html

I notice that there is a rotationSpace property that may come in handy, and also a rotateRelativeWithQuaternion method.

I'm hoping that maybe someone out there who is familiar with this problem and can see how to wield this API to slay it.

Answer (score 0):

```
_cube1.rotationSpace = NGLRotationSpaceWorld;
```

does the trick!

Resources:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5DzKP6y0nU&list=UUJ0dpXJSjM9rpDtx6ZdPXHw

http://nineveh.gl/docs/Classes/NGLObject3D.html

http://nineveh.gl/docs/Classes/NGLObject3D.html#//api/name/rotationSpace